# Security hotspot issue with regex in sonar qube

Tags: java, regex, sonarqube

The issue is:

Make sure the regex used here, which is vulnerable to polynomial runtime due to backtracking, cannot lead to denial of service.
Using slow regular expressions is security-sensitivejava:S5852

```
        String splitRegex = "(\\s*°\\s*)|(\\s*'{1,2}\\s*)";
        String[] latData = expPoint.getLatDegree().split(splitRegex);
        if (latData.length == 4) {
            point.setLatitudeDegree(Integer.valueOf(latData[0]));
            point.setLatitudeMinute(Integer.valueOf(latData[1]));
            point.setLatitudeSecond(Double.valueOf(latData[2]));
            point.setLatitudeQuad("N".equals(latData[3]));
        }
```

The hotspot issue is on split function. How to avoid the hotspot issue? Any alternative?

Comment: What is your regex supposed to be doing?

Comment: Sonarqube have links on issues "Why is this an issue?" and when you click on that, it opens a drawer from the bottom of the window where are described all possible reasons.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is used for splitting the value we are getting of latitude. example: lat is "15°24'15" output is 15 24 15.0

Comment: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-5852: `One example of this would be to replace str.split("\\s*,\\s*") with str.split(",") and then trimming the spaces from the strings as a second step`